# Wordpress - connection information

Tags: plugins, installation, hosting

[image]

I am entering valid details, though wordpress keep prompting same as follows. What would be the wrong thing ?

Edit : Even after modifying the permissions as follows, I am getting same errors.[image]

Comment: there might be a firewall setup on your server not allowing ftp/sftp connections

Comment: yeah...Paul told Correctly.Me also Faced this type of  problem's before....

Comment: hmm ! Need to check with the server-admin for such cases. But he previously mentioned that - my site is hosted over VPS. ( I don't know much about VPS )

Comment: +1 with pauls suggestion, i believe if you have a static IP that your server admin can allow that IP permission, will be other ways i imagine if not.

Comment: :'( :( I got stuck. I am not able to upload plugins, neither manually nor using wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly a permissions problem - your `wp-content` folder must be writable by your webserver user.

Typically setting permissions to `755` will sort this.